# Dockerized react app doesn't work on localhost

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, docker-compose

I have the following Dockerfile for the server:

```
FROM node:18.13.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 8080    
CMD [ "npm", "run", "start"]
```

and for the client:

```
FROM node:18.13.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000    
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

and the docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  server:
    build: ./server
    container_name: e_commerce_server_container
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - ./server:/app
      - /app/node_modules

  client:
    build: ./client
    container_name: e_commerce_client_container
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - ./client:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    # stdin_open: true
    # tty: true
```

when I run `docker-compose up --build` and try to access the server on `localhost:8080` is working, but for `localhost:3000` to see my react app is not working.

What should I do? I've tried a lot of methods but noting happened.

Comment: “not working” in what way? blank page? connection refused?

Comment: I get the "This page isn’t working localhost didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE", and in the terminal looks something like 
e_commerce_client_container  |   vite v2.9.15 dev server running at: Local: http://localhost:3000/

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue. It looks like it was from vite, I should add the "vite --host 0.0.0.0" and now it works